# SLURM : Shell commands cause following #SBATCH commands to not get parsed

Tags: bash, slurm

I am new to SLURM and using it with OpenMP.  I created a C program, `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

void wait(int s)
{
    int waittime = time(0) + s;
    while(time(0) < waittime);
}


int main(void)
{
    int id=-1;
    int nthreads = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel \
    private(id)
    {   
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello from thread = %i\n",id);

        if(id == 0)
            printf("nthreads = %i\n", nthreads);

        //Let's wait
        wait(60);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

and a slurm batch script, `slurm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10
#SBATCH --job-name=OpenMP
#SBATCH --output output.txt
echo "Hello"

#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100  

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10

./a.out
```

If I submit (i.e. `sbatch slurm.sh`), this SLURM happily allocates 10 cpus for my job.  If I put the `echo "Hello"` before `#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10`, I only get allocated 1 CPU.  What is going on here?  I do not understand why, the location of a shell command in my batch script changes how many cpus get allocated.

**::Edit::** Upon further inspection it appears that *any* shell command (e.g. `date`, `echo`, `set`) seems to cause sbatch to ignore all following `#SBATCH` commands.  For instance in my batch script, I can set `#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1000000` and it will happily run on a 128GB machine.  If I move `#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1000000` to a line before the `echo`, SLURM appropriately gives me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add any command between `#SBATCH` directives.

From the `sbatch` man page:

> The batch script may contain options preceded with
>          "#SBATCH" before any executable commands in the script.

Comment: That is a soft statement in the man page.  It would be better if it contained the statement "Executables before any #SBATCH directive will break the sbatch parser"